# iOS - How to check similar video in cameraroll?

Tags: avfoundation, histogram, core-video, core-media

I wanna check all video in cameraroll.
Which video are similar together. Any way to check the content of those?
I research about AVFoundation, Coremedia, corevideo in iOS but not found.
PS: I found a way but I think not good is we check some first frames of video and compare by histogram.
Thanks all

Comment: This sounds like a hard and computationally expensive problem. Is there something specific you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to find duplicate or similar video to remove for release the storage.  I just find 2 libs

Comment: https://github.com/ameingast/cocoaimagehashing and https://github.com/chrisdanford/Tidy